# Doctrine query using execute

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

`Option 1` and `Option 2` seem to give similar results. Is there a particular advantage for using the `execute statement` rather than the usual `getResult()` method?

### Option 1:

```
public function getEventsByOrganiser(EventInterface $event, $username)
{
    $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select(array('e', 'u'))
        ->leftJoin('e.user', 'u')
        ->andWhere('u.username = :username');

    return $qb->getQuery()->execute(array(
        'username' => $username
    ));
}
```

### Option2:

```
public function getEventsByOrganiser(EventInterface $event, $username)
{
    $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select(array('e', 'u'))
        ->leftJoin('e.user', 'u')
        ->andWhere('u.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically `getResult()` is alias for `execute(array())` you can set as argument hydration mode for example: `getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT)` is `execute(array(), Query::HYDRTE_OBJECT)`

Only difference: in execute method you can set query parameters as first argument so you do not have to call `setParameter` method before...

Comment: Just citing the doc for people to look into if they need to: [query-result-formats](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats)